# how to find the bound form of an enzyme structure?

Tags: database, protein-structure

For my undergraduate research I'm looking for a database that gives the bound form of a particular protein structure. Is there any database that provide us with such data? So far I've found following proteins related to my work

- Ascorbate peroxidase (APX)
- Beta-glucosidase
- Calcineurin b-like protein-interacting protein kinase.

I've searched in PDB and UNIPROT.

Comment: Hi Lock23, thanks for your question and welcome to Bioinformatics Stack Exchange. After reading your question, I did a quick check on the [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=enzyme+database) and [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=enzyme+database) Stack Exchanges, and was surprised at how little "database" stuff there was.

Comment: For experimentally determined structures PDB is the database and it's unlikely you'll find structures that are publicly available but not in the PDB. There is also protein structure prediction software (servers).

Answer (score 5):

Tried looking for an explicit database? i.e.

- ComSin: database of protein structures in bound (complex) and unbound (single) states in relation to their intrinsic disorder: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2808974/ or
- LigASite: a database of biologically relevant binding sites in proteins with known apo-structures https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17933762

Else the PDB itself has a very powerful advanced search that should allow you to do this: http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/search/advSearch.do

Answer (score 4):

Are you aware of [BRENDA](http://www.brenda-enzymes.org/index.php)? I was just introduced to it today for a completely separate reason (looking at carbohydrate enzyme families in the *Nippostrongylus brasiliensis* proteome), and it seems to be a fairly comprehensive database. There is at least a literature link there for the [ascorbate-complexed crystalisation of Ascorbate peroxidase](http://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.11.1.11#Crystallization/COMMENTARY) on that site. Following through the paper, I see that [the complex has been uploaded to PDB](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?pdbId=1OAF).